# What is the meaning of this security group declaration in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-security-group

Reading some tf code for a postgresql related vpc security group, I see this

```
resource "aws_security_group" "xxx" { 
  name        = "xxx"
  description = "xxx" 
  vpc_id      = xxxx
  ingress {
    description = "xxxx"
    from_port   = 5432
    to_port     = 5432
    protocol    = "TCP"
    self        = true
  }
}
```

What does this ingress allows? What does the ***self*** mean and what is the significance of same ***from_port*** and ***to_port***?

I went through the documentation but I am still not very clear.

Comment: I think you may need to read AWS and Postgres documentation instead of TF documentation.

Comment: @MattSchuchard How is reading pg docs going to help me. I could run any process on 5432 instead of RDS and will still have this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From port and to port allows you to define a range of ports. For example lets say you had an app that listened on port `5000, 5001, 5002, 5003, 5004, 5005`. Instead of defining a rule for each port you could just say `from_port = 5000` and `to_port = 5005`. it is effectivly defning a range or ports like `5000 - 5005`. In your exmaple since the from and to port are the same it will only allow traffic on that port and no other. From the terraform docs

```
from_port - (Required) Start port (or ICMP type number if protocol is icmp or icmpv6).
to_port - (Required) End range port (or ICMP code if protocol is icmp).
```

As for the self part, this means it will allow allow traffic from any other interface within the same security group. I.E that has this security group assigned to it. its saying I only accept inbound traffic from myself. I.E anything which has this security group can send to port 5432 to anything else with this security group.

```
self - (Optional) Whether the security group itself will be added as a source to this ingress rule.
```

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/security_group